# Cutting off top of image depending on background image container

Tags: css, background, background-image

I have a container with a background image. This container is a variable height, depending on the content inside it. As the container gets smaller, I would like to progressively cut off the bottom of the background image, while still keeping it in the same place.

I have played around with background-size and background-position but I haven’t been able to achieve this. Any advice?

Basically I would like to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/tdgbu6kv/2/

```
.one {
  height: 500px;
}

.two {
  height: 100px;
}

.image {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-size: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600)
}
```

but instead of it cutting off the top of the image, I would like it to cut off the bottom

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your code.

Comment: updated to include a fiddle